# Animated number counter not showing decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning all,

I have an animated number counter that counts up from 0 to the specified number. However if I enter a decimal number (i.e. 99.99%) it rounds up to 100%. Is there a way to make it count up to the number that is given?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance!

```js
numbersAnimate(_Panel) {

    if (!_Panel) {
      return;
    }

    // Get document language
    const _Document = document.documentElement;
    let lang = _Document.getAttribute('lang');

    // Grab all panel amount nodes
    const _PanelAmounts = _Panel.querySelectorAll('.panel__amount');
    if (!_PanelAmounts) {
      return;
    }

    //Loop over all the panel amounts
    for (const _PanelAmount of _PanelAmounts) {

      //Convert to jQuery object
      const $PanelAmount = $(_PanelAmount);

      //Panel amount stored in value
      const value = $PanelAmount.data('amount');

      //If there is no value return
      if (!value || value.length < 1) {
        return;
      }

      // If not a number return
      if (isNaN(value)) {
        return;
      }

      //Animation....
      $PanelAmount.prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: value
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function(now) {
          $PanelAmount.text(this.Counter.toFixed());
        }
      });

    }

    //Add animated class because scroll event checks if it's there, if it isn't then add it.
    _Panel.classList.add('animated');





    //JSON Structure

    "statistic": {
      "amount": "99.99",
      "symbol": "%"
    },
```

```html
<span className="panel__amount panel-text-style-c" data-amount={jsonData.statistic.amount}>0</span>
```

Comment: This is caused by your use of `Math.ceil()` - remove it. Also note that the `toLocaleString()` isn't actually preforming any worthwhile action. Did you mean to call it on the result of the `ceil()` call instead?

Comment: Hey Rory. Thank you for the reply, if i remove the Math.ceil() the numbers jump around before animating which is a weird visual behaviour, that is why i have kept it in. Do you know if there is some kind of work around?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you mean by 'jump around'? Possibly due to rounding, so try `now.toFixed(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for my bad explanation. The numbers seem to just move up and down when animating - once it has finished they resume in the correct position, when i have added int the toFixed(1) it is giving me 99.0% instead of 99.99%? Is there anything else i need to do, many thanks.

Comment: Could you add more of your code in to a snippet in the question. It's hard to diagnose a specific problem without seeing it in action

Comment: Hi Rory, i have added my JS, JSX and JSON structure, hope that helps - thank you very much for the input so far.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Math.ceil(now)` which will round to the nearest integer. Have you tried removing it?

```
$PanelAmount.text(now).toLocaleString(lang);
```

Comment: Hi, when i try and remove it, the numbers jump around when animating. It is hard to explain really as it is a visual issue when removed, but once I have removed it it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Old:

```
//Panel amount is the animated number

$PanelAmount.prop('Counter', 0).animate({
  Counter: value
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function(now) {
    $PanelAmount.text(Math.ceil(now)).toLocaleString(lang);
  }
});
```

New:

```js
function startCounter(){
 $('.PanelAmount').each(function (index) {
        var size = $(this).text().split(".")[1] ? $(this).text().split(".")[1].length : 0;
     $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
         Counter: $(this).text()
     }, {
         duration: 2000,
         easing: 'swing',
         step: function (now) {
             $(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(size));
         }
     });
 });
} 

startCounter();
```

```css
.PanelAmount {
  
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter">99.99</div>
```

New JQuery works to the exact decimal point

Comment: Hi Billy, it is almost there, but now it isn't giving accurate results (when i type in 99.99 it returns 98.89) do you know why this is - thanks!

Comment: Hi Mark. Have revised my anwser, to see this running go here: https://jsfiddle.net/billy_farroll/5uxo5thb/1/ works to the exact decimal point.

Comment: Hi dude, thanks for the reply, is there a way I can implement your changes within my already defined function (edited above)